# ¿Cómo enviar opciones a php con botones?

Tags: php, html

Estoy haciendo una página en la que inicias sesión y una vez dentro, según el botón que toques, hará una acción determinada. Por ejemplo, cerrar sesión.
Se me ocurrió un `form` en el que agregue los botones, asignarles un valor y un nombre, algo así:

```
<form action="paginaopciones.php" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" value="1" name="Opcion">Opc1</button>
    <button type="submit" value="2" name="Opcion">Opc2</button>
    <button type="submit" value="3" name="Opcion">Salir</button>
</form>
```

Y ya el php (`paginaopciones.php` en este caso) sería algo así:

```
<?php
$opcion = $_POST['Opcion'];

if($opcion == 3)
{
    //Destruye la sesion y redirecciona al inicio
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: Inicio.php');
}
?>
```

Pero no funciona.
Entonces ¿Saben alguna alternativa o qué podría hacer?
Gracias

Comment: ¿Compruebas que al PHP te llegan los datos correctamente? ¿Has comprobado que ambos ficheros estén en la misma carpeta y se llamen igual (mayúsculas y minúsculas)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="paginaopciones.php" method="POST">
   <button type="submit" value="1" name="Opcion1">Opc1</button>
   <button type="submit" value="2" name="Opcion2">Opc2</button>
   <button type="submit" value="3" name="Opcion3">Salir</button>
</form>
```

En los nombres (`"name"`) debes darles un nombre diferente, y luego ya pasando a php, y si quieres seguir de ese modo seria algo como:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['Opcion3']))
{
  //Destruye la sesion y redirecciona al inicio
  session_destroy();
  header('Location: Inicio.php');
 }
?>
```

`isset` sirve para saber que un valor esta declarado, entonces si existe es que se selecciono la `opcion 3`, y ya entra al `if`.